# Fragment isn't able to be cast

Tags: android, casting, fragment

In my activity file, I have

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

if (fragment == null){
    fragment = new CrimeFragment();
}
```

The class `CrimeFragment` is in another java file, called `CrimeFragment.java`, where it's defined as

```
public class CrimeFragment extends Fragment {

    private Crime mCrime;
    private EditText mTitlefield;

}
```

I get an error in Android Studio saying that `fragment` needs a Fragment object but is being given a CrimeFragment object. Shouldn't this be no problem though since CrimeFragment extends Fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you're importing different Fragment objects, the normal one, and the android.support.v4.app.Fragment one.

Comment: I will when it lets me